# lazy loading mapping objects from 2 different server GET requests

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Hello i need to query 2 GET requests for 4 -20 dashboards.I was wondering what's a good way to map the second query with the first query?

I am using angularjs `$resource`, do i have to loop through each object and match them through a unique property? (both id's are the same in both objects) but what if one object is un-ordered while the other is ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small arrays, the easiest way is to loop through the primary array with angular.foreach and call the $filter service to find the correct matching item in the second array. Pseudo code:

```
angular.forEach(primaryArray, function(item, key) {
    item.secondaryItem = $filter('filter')(secondaryArray, {sharedId === item.sharedId})[0]
}
```

Also I recommend calling both those REST $resource service queries by getting the promises and joining them back using the $q.all() method.

Comment: would this also work for deep copy of objects? my get requests return several objects and i need to match the objects from the 2 different get requests.

Comment: yes, this should not be a concern, as long as you define your json query correctly.